# Random ConnectionError using python-socketio on the client side

Tags: python, socket.io, connection, python-socketio

I am using `python-socketio` to connect to a third party server using the socketIO protocol.
The server is out of my control, therefore I do not have access to server side logs, etc... .
The error below happens randomly (say half of the times), so my current workaround is to retry until the connection succeeds.

I have found other posts where the same exception is thrown, but in those cases it was a systematic error and the corresponding solutions do not apply to my case.

Any help to completely avoid the exception?

**Code**

```py
# sio_mwe.py

from socketio import Client

sio_url = 'https://r.thewebsite.net?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret'

sio = Client(logger=True, engineio_logger=True, reconnection_attempts=5)
sio.on('*', lambda x: print("Inside handler:", x))

sio.connect(sio_url, socketio_path='r')
print("-- CONNECTED --")

sio.emit('signal', data=f'mydata')
print("-- EMITTED --")
```

**Logs**

Below you can find the logs generated when the above MWE has been repeatedly executed.

```
$ python sio_mwe.py 
Attempting polling connection to https://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=polling&EIO=4
Polling connection accepted with {'sid': 'ghfrdZaKRjVS2vcBACqE', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'maxPayload': 1000000}
Engine.IO connection established
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{}
Attempting WebSocket upgrade to wss://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=websocket&EIO=4
WebSocket upgrade was successful
Received packet MESSAGE data 0{"sid":"7TWzrBV3ehhR212PACqG"}
Namespace / is connected
-- CONNECTED --
Emitting event "signal" [/]
Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["signal","mydata"]
-- EMITTED --
$ python sio_mwe.py 
Attempting polling connection to https://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=polling&EIO=4
Polling connection accepted with {'sid': 'yiL2tFH4gy4FjExvACqI', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'maxPayload': 1000000}
Engine.IO connection established
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{}
Attempting WebSocket upgrade to wss://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=websocket&EIO=4
WebSocket upgrade was successful
Received packet MESSAGE data 0{"sid":"UpcoKLNq0X_ifz7oACqJ"}
Namespace / is connected
-- CONNECTED --
Emitting event "signal" [/]
Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["signal","mydata"]
-- EMITTED --
$ python sio_mwe.py 
Attempting polling connection to https://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=polling&EIO=4
Polling connection accepted with {'sid': 'qmWjIe407V-92_7_ACqK', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'maxPayload': 1000000}
Engine.IO connection established
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{}
Attempting WebSocket upgrade to wss://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=websocket&EIO=4
WebSocket upgrade was successful
WebSocket connection was closed, aborting
Waiting for write loop task to end
Exiting write loop task
Engine.IO connection dropped
Connection failed, new attempt in 1.45 seconds
Exiting read loop task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "**OMISSIS**/sio_mwe.py", line 39, in <module>
    sio.connect(sio_url, socketio_path='r')
  File "**OMISSIS**/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/client.py", line 163, in connect
    raise exceptions.ConnectionError(
socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: One or more namespaces failed to connect
$ python sio_mwe.py 
Attempting polling connection to https://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=polling&EIO=4
Polling connection accepted with {'sid': 'bsU8bGZDK3C-dLEYACqS', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'maxPayload': 1000000}
Engine.IO connection established
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{}
Attempting WebSocket upgrade to wss://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=websocket&EIO=4
WebSocket upgrade was successful
WebSocket connection was closed, aborting
Waiting for write loop task to end
Exiting write loop task
Engine.IO connection dropped
Connection failed, new attempt in 1.33 seconds
Exiting read loop task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "**OMISSIS**/sio_mwe.py", line 39, in <module>
    sio.connect(sio_url, socketio_path='r')
  File "**OMISSIS**/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/client.py", line 163, in connect
    raise exceptions.ConnectionError(
socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: One or more namespaces failed to connect
$ python sio_mwe.py 
Attempting polling connection to https://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=polling&EIO=4
Polling connection accepted with {'sid': '6TqMXBDJspZBe92YACqY', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'maxPayload': 1000000}
Engine.IO connection established
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{}
Attempting WebSocket upgrade to wss://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=websocket&EIO=4
WebSocket upgrade was successful
Received packet MESSAGE data 0{"sid":"P10loKi4B23X79xqACqZ"}
Namespace / is connected
-- CONNECTED --
Emitting event "signal" [/]
Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["signal","mydata"]
-- EMITTED --
$ python sio_mwe.py 
Attempting polling connection to https://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=polling&EIO=4
Polling connection accepted with {'sid': 'AmSCvIsjdRpnsdHwACqc', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'maxPayload': 1000000}
Engine.IO connection established
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{}
Attempting WebSocket upgrade to wss://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=websocket&EIO=4
WebSocket upgrade was successful
Received packet MESSAGE data 0{"sid":"veuDxr2k5dLLfX20ACqd"}
Namespace / is connected
-- CONNECTED --
Emitting event "signal" [/]
Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["signal","mydata"]
-- EMITTED --
$ python sio_mwe.py 
Attempting polling connection to https://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=polling&EIO=4
Polling connection accepted with {'sid': '2tiYT9ZTqRiumIv4ACqe', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'maxPayload': 1000000}
Engine.IO connection established
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{}
Attempting WebSocket upgrade to wss://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=websocket&EIO=4
WebSocket upgrade was successful
WebSocket connection was closed, aborting
Waiting for write loop task to end
Exiting write loop task
Engine.IO connection dropped
Connection failed, new attempt in 0.85 seconds
Exiting read loop task
Attempting polling connection to https://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=polling&EIO=4
Polling connection accepted with {'sid': 'PAOF0QWb1rfW0f9-ACqg', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'maxPayload': 1000000}
Engine.IO connection established
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{}
Attempting WebSocket upgrade to wss://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=websocket&EIO=4
Sending packet CLOSE data None
Engine.IO connection dropped
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "**OMISSIS**/sio_mwe.py", line 39, in <module>
    sio.connect(sio_url, socketio_path='r')
  File "**OMISSIS**/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/client.py", line 163, in connect
    raise exceptions.ConnectionError(
socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: One or more namespaces failed to connect
$ python sio_mwe.py 
Attempting polling connection to https://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=polling&EIO=4
Polling connection accepted with {'sid': 'H-81bc5akux_oi7MACqq', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'maxPayload': 1000000}
Engine.IO connection established
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{}
Attempting WebSocket upgrade to wss://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=websocket&EIO=4
WebSocket upgrade was successful
WebSocket connection was closed, aborting
Waiting for write loop task to end
Exiting write loop task
Engine.IO connection dropped
Connection failed, new attempt in 1.44 seconds
Exiting read loop task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "**OMISSIS**/sio_mwe.py", line 39, in <module>
    sio.connect(sio_url, socketio_path='r')
  File "**OMISSIS**/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/client.py", line 163, in connect
    raise exceptions.ConnectionError(
socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: One or more namespaces failed to connect
$ python sio_mwe.py 
Attempting polling connection to https://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=polling&EIO=4
Polling connection accepted with {'sid': 'vacxuBJMCJrBZq7xACqs', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'maxPayload': 1000000}
Engine.IO connection established
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{}
Attempting WebSocket upgrade to wss://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=websocket&EIO=4
WebSocket upgrade was successful
WebSocket connection was closed, aborting
Waiting for write loop task to end
Exiting write loop task
Engine.IO connection dropped
Connection failed, new attempt in 0.55 seconds
Exiting read loop task
Attempting polling connection to https://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=polling&EIO=4
Polling connection accepted with {'sid': '37uV5uncNZ69q-CJACqx', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'maxPayload': 1000000}
Engine.IO connection established
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{}
Attempting WebSocket upgrade to wss://r.thewebsite.net/r/?user=myuser&name=myname&credentials=mysecret&transport=websocket&EIO=4
WebSocket upgrade was successful
Received packet MESSAGE data 0{"sid":"pvYNYRBEBN0qVIDWACqy"}
Namespace / is connected
-- CONNECTED --
Reconnection successful
Emitting event "signal" [/]
Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["signal","mydata"]
-- EMITTED --
```

**Versions**

Client:

- Python: 3.10
- python-engineio: 4.9.0
- python-socketio: 5.11.1

Server:

- SocketIO: 4.5.0

Comment: See the troubleshooting section of the python-socketio documentation to learn how to enable logs. Then attach your logs to your question please.

Comment: I don't see any Socket.IO logs. The logs that you are showing come from your own app and from other components such as urllib3. You have to enable Socket.IO logs.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that those lines logged from `urllib3.connectionpool` were all you was expecting... evidently not. I'll try to setup a mwe to avoid any interference due to other parts of my program (such as my custom log configuration). Anyway, passing `logger=True, engineio_logger=True` to the SioClient should be enough to get the logs printed on the screen, right?

Comment: Hi, I updated the question. Turned out that `logger=True, engineio_logger=True` was not working as in my original program I created another `Client` without logging enabled before creating the troublesome one, and the first client set the log level for all the others to come.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg sorry to bother, any hint on this?

Comment: The log indicates that the server is closing the connection in the cases that ended in failure. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the server is out of my control. I guess I'll have to keep it as is.